# Is there an R function (in terra?) that takes a raster (representing a map) and returns a raster of the areas of the patch to which each cell belongs?

Tags: r, matrix, raster, spatial, terra

I've written an R function that takes a raster-based map, and counts the area and perimeter of patches of a given habitat type. However, it's vectorised, hence painfully slow on large maps. I need something much faster, and I assume that there is something in 'raster' or 'terra' that will work. However, I've not managed it yet (see below).

By way of illustration, if I had a map with patches of land-cover type '7' as follows:

```
matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,7,
7,0,0,0,0,0,7,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,7,0,0,0),nrow=6,byrow=T)
```

I would want a raster wherein each cell shows the area of the patch it's in, i.e.:

```
matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
5,5,0,0,0,0,0,
5,5,0,0,0,0,2,
5,0,0,0,0,0,2,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0),nrow=6,byrow=T)
```

And another with the perimeter:

```
matrix(c(0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,
10,10,0,0,0,0,0,
10,10,0,0,0,0,6,
10, 0,0,0,0,0,6,
0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,
0, 0, 0,4,0,0,0),nrow=6,byrow=T)
```

For the area, I have tried the following:

```
library(terra)
vals<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,7,
7,0,0,0,0,0,7,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,7,0,0,0)

# Make into raster object for terra
r <- rast(nrows=6, ncols=7)
values(r)<-vals
# Create map of clumps (patches)
p <- patches(r, zeroAsNA=TRUE)
plot(p) 
# This finds the three patches, but doesn't give 
# them unique names (=problem)

# Create blank raster of the same dimensions (not sure if needed)
blank<-rast(nrows=6, ncols=7)
values(blank)<-0

# Convert p to a polygon
polyg <- as.polygons(p)
plot(polyg)

# Rasterize polyg, returning the area
ss<-rasterizeGeom(polyg,blank,fun="area",unit='m')
plot(ss)
```

This clearly isn't what I want!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(terra)
vals<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,7,
7,0,0,0,0,0,7,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,7,0,0,0)

# Make into raster object for terra
r <- rast(nrows=6, ncols=7,xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=7,ymax=6)
values(r)<-vals
crs(r)<-"local"

# Create map of clumps (patches)
p <- patches(r,zeroAsNA=TRUE)
plot(p)

# Create blank raster of the same dimensions (not sure if needed)
blank<-rast(nrows=6, ncols=7,xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=7,ymax=6)
values(blank)<-0
blank<-extend(blank,c(1,1))
crs(blank)<-"local"

# Convert p to a polygon
polyg <- as.polygons(p)
plot(polyg)

# To get the raster of perimeters
perimrast<-rasterize(polyg,blank,field=perim(polyg))

# To get the areas
arearast<-rasterize(polyg,blank,field=expanse(polyg))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were mistaken when you said

> This finds the three patches, but doesn't give
> them unique names (=problem)

You have to consider that -180° is adjacent to 180° longitude (the world has no end).

It is easier to interpret the results with a raster that does not span the entire globe as I do below. Here is how you can find patches are replace them with the patch area.

```
library(terra)
vals <- 
c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,0,
7,7,0,0,0,0,7,
7,0,0,0,0,0,7,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,7,0,0,0)

r <- rast(nrows=6, ncols=7, xmin=0, vals=vals)
p <- patches(r, zeroAsNA=TRUE)
plot(p) 

a <-  expanse(p, byValue=TRUE)
x <- classify(p, a[,2:3])
```

`boundaries` identifies the edges of patches, but there is no way to directly compute the perimeter (an oversight). So your approach to create polygons is probably the best available.

```
pol <- as.polygons(p)
pol$per <- perim(pol)
x <- rasterize(pol, r, "per")
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - yes, I only just twigged that the raster map is 'wrap-around'!